# Create new Js Array of Object with new key name from old objects

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a new `Array of Object` from the data which is another array of objects coming from API.
The new Array which we will get in the end should get value from `dataFromApi` and updated key names to will be selected from another array that holds the previous `key` and `new key name | label` for those properties. This data will be exported in CSV file. So we are using reusable components for this export, I want to make this conversion of data dynamic. As the current key name looks like `currentApplyStart` and in the CSV file they are not good headers.

So,

We are getting a new key names array from this function. What this function is trying to solve is, get the pair of `oldKeyName and its newKeyName || new key and label`

```
const newKeyName = () =>  { 
if (data?.length) {
            const allColumn = Object.keys(data?.[0]);
            const columnKeys = dataColumns
                .filter((header) => allColumn.indexOf(header.key) >= 0)
                .map((column) => {
                    return { key: column.key, label: column.label };
                });
            return columnKeys;
        };
}
```

which return something like this. This is demo data.

```
let dataColumns = [
{key : 'color', label : 'newColor'} , 
{key : 'annoying', label : 'newAnnoying'},
key : 'height', label : 'newHeight'}
//  we only return these top three as the api data object consist only has these two keys in itself.
{key : 'meta', label : 'newMeta'}
{key : 'costApplyStart', label : 'CPA'}
]
```

```
let newKeyNames = [
{key : 'color', label : 'newColor'} , 
{key : 'annoying', label : 'newAnnoying'},
{key : 'height', label : 'newHeight'} ] 
// as only these three key name exist in dataFromApi.
```

So let's say we have an array of the object which comes from API

```
let DataFromApi = [
{ 
  color: 'red',
  annoying: true,
  height: 'unknown',
},
{ 
  color: 'blue',
  annoying: false,
  height: 'unknown',
},
{ 
  color: 'red',
  annoying: false,
  height: 'unknown',
},
];
```

The data which i want it in the end should be like this

```
let finalData = [
{newColor: 'red',newAnnoying: true, newHeight: 'unknown',}, 
{newColor: 'blue',newAnnoying: false, newHeight: 'unknown',}
{
  color: 'red',
  annoying: 'false,
  newHeight: 'unknown',
},
]
```

Observe is data, that I changed the old key name into a new key which I want to be header in csvFile.  I can not mutate the original data , for that reason i have to create a new data array .
The solution i tried was this but I was not getting the desired result.

```
  newKeyNames?.map((field) => {
                return dataFromAPi.map((item) => {
                    if (item.hasOwnProperty(field.key)) {
                        item[field.label] = item[field.key];
                    }
                });
            });
```

Comment: is this what you are looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/ghkedmx6/

Comment: No, sorry i forgot to mention the `newKeyNames` array is not static, it changes according to the data coming from API. `new key names array` is made dynamcially from apiData.

Comment: As per my understanding, you have to convert `DataFromApi` array to `finalData` by taking the keys from `newKeyNames`. You need to have the keys from each object in `DataFromApi` array by comparing with `newKeyNames`. From the example, you need to take the keys `color` and `annoying` and map it as `newColor` and `newAnnoying`. But can you explain me why your `finalData` has only 2 objects when `dataFromAPi` has 3 objects?

Comment: Yes, you are right Nitheesh. Yes, I want all object key-value pairs. Sorry, i missed the third object. Let me update it in question. In short Every property in object should have its new key name so that csv file have nice headers. So all the key name and all object will be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the later explanation, I've updated the answer.

Here's the JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/_ghost/py8et9vf/57/

```js
let DataFromApi = [
  { 
    color: 'red',
    annoying: true,
    height: 'unknown',
    meta: { one: '1', two: '2'}
  },
  { 
    color: 'blue',
    annoying: false,
    height: 'unknown',
    meta: { one: '1', two: '2'}
  },
  { 
    color: 'red',
    annoying: true,
    height: 'unknown',
    meta: { one: '1', two: '2'}
  },
];

let dataColumns = [
  {key : 'color', label : 'newColor'} , 
  {key : 'annoying', label : 'newAnnoying'},
  {key : 'somekey', label : 'newSomeKey'},
  {key : 'anotherKey', label : 'newAnotherKey'}
]

function getAllDataCols(){
    let obj = {};
  
  // Make a new object from all the dataColums for ease of use
  
  dataColumns.forEach(item => {
    obj[item.key] = item.label
  })
  
  return obj
}

function processDataFromApi(newDataCols){

    let result = []

    DataFromApi.forEach(obj => {
  
    let newObj = {}
  
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(name => {
            
        if(newDataCols[name] !== undefined){
            //if we have an alternative for the name
          
          newObj[newDataCols[name]] = obj[name]
        }else{
            // we don't have an alternative. use the already existing name
            newObj[name] = obj[name]
        }
      
    })
    
    result.push(newObj)
  })
    
  return result
}

let newDataCols = getAllDataCols()

let response = processDataFromApi(newDataCols)

console.log(response)
```

Comment: Hey @adib , sorry but this wasn't not i am looking for. I have rearranegd my question to get to understand it more clearly. The thing is you don't have to bother about keyname they are coming from arrayOfObject , i just want data from api should have new labels which is already been given by another function nad make new data array from it. As i can't export oldKeyName as csvHeader for my export file.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?
https://jsfiddle.net/_ghost/py8et9vf/57/

Comment: Hey , i have checked it , and it worked. Doing some more testing. Can you update your answer so that i can vote it

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can start with converting your `newKeyNames` array into an object or a map. Then use `Object.entries` to destruct your object into `[key,value]` pairs and then apply renaming to these pairs and a build a new object using `Object.fromEtnries` from these pairs.

```js
let newKeyNames = new Map([{
    key: 'color',
    label: 'newColor'
  },
  {
    key: 'annoying',
    label: 'newAnnoying'
  },
  {
    key: 'height',
    label: 'newHeight'
  }
].map(({
  key,
  label
}) => [key, label]));

const dataFromApi = [{
    color: 'red',
    annoying: true,
    height: 'unknown',
  },
  {
    color: 'blue',
    annoying: false,
    height: 'unknown',
  },
  {
    color: 'red',
    annoying: false,
    height: 'unknown',
  },
];

const renamedObjectArray = dataFromApi.map(item => Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(item)
  .filter(([key, ]) => newKeyNames.get(key)) // this will filter out the properties that doesn't exist on newKeyNames map
  .map(([key, val]) => [newKeyNames.get(key), val]) // this will rebuild an object with renamed keys
));

console.log(renamedObjectArray)
```